# How to delete file with spaces using appium?

Tags: python, android, appium

I am testing my application and as part of the current scenario, I need to delete files after I finish my tests.

My file name is with spaces: `Application Log.txt`

This is what i have try:

```
adb shell rm /sdcard/app name /logs/Application Log.txt
```

And i got this message:

```
rm: name/logs/Application: No such file or directory
rm: Log.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `My file name is with spaces`. Yes. And how many spaces do you count here: `/app name /`?

Comment: And you did not tell if you can delete a file if full path is without spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to escape the space

```
Application\ Log.txt
```

Another thing which might work is putting the name in quotes

```
"Application Log.txt"
```

Comment: Ok so your first option works not but i got the message: rm: /sdcard/app name /logs/Application Log.txt: No such file or directory although the file exist